# Python3 Tkinter display Listbox items in a Label when clicked

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, listbox

I have this listbox as part of a class:

```
def myListbox(self):
selection = Label(self, text="Please select Country").grid(row=0,column=0)

countries = Listbox(self, width = 20, height = 75)
countries.grid(row=0, column=1)

# I have a function that populates the country names from
# a text file and displays the names in the Listbox.
# I want to be able to select a country from the Listbox
# and have it displayed in a Label

country_display = Label(self, text = "").grid(row = 0, column = 9)
# this is where I'm not sure what code to use.
# my code is
countries.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>",country_display)
```

At the moment nothing is displaying. What am I missing here?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you perform the method `grid` on a widget, it will return `None`. This means that your variable now holds the value `None`, instead of the reference to the widget.
Secondly, the method `bind`, binds a function to an event. This function cannot be called yet. However, in your `bind`, you try to assign the `Label` (which is not a function) to the event; this is simply not possible. 
In the solution below, a function is assigned to the event, which retrieves the country, and sets the label.

```
from tkinter import *

countries_list = ["Netherlands",
                  "America",
                  "Sweden",
                  "England"]

class MyClass(Tk):
    def myListbox(self):

        # better to structure it this way. The method grid simply returns None
        # which meant that the variable hold None
        # Now, the variable selection holds the widget
        selection = Label(self, text="Please select Country")
        selection.grid(row=0,column=0)

        countries = Listbox(self, width = 20, height = len(countries_list))
        countries.grid(row=0, column=1)
        for country in countries_list:
            countries.insert(END, country)

        country_display = Label(self, text = country, width = 15)
        country_display.grid(row = 0, column = 9)

        def get_country(*x):
            # gets which country is selected, and changes
            # the label accordingly
            country = countries_list[countries.curselection()[0]]
            country_display.config(text = country)
        countries.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", get_country)

app = MyClass()
app.myListbox()
```

edit: for more information on `Listbox` see http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm
(although I get the feeling you might want to use a `Combobox`, as described in http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/widgets.html?)